# What is a good Wordpress plugin to upload a photo to a page?

Tags: upload, wordpress

I have a site where each page has 3 photos in the header. I want the user to be able to switch out the photos that appear on each pages header.

I'm looking for a wordpress plugin which will allow the admin to upload photos to a specified location for a certain page.

Does anyone know of a wordpress plugin with that sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a plugin but custom field solution you might want to add, have a look at:

[Using Custom fields in WordPress to attach images or files to your posts](http://www.bydust.com/using-custom-fields-in-wordpress-to-attach-images-or-files-to-your-posts/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are searching for: [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-public-uploader/) (NextGEN Public Uploader)

Answer (score 0):

I use this one. You can create customized forms and its free:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contest-gallery/